# Benefit of Enumerables

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I am struggling to understand the benefit of IEnumerable.  I understand that Enumerables allow execution to be deferred to later on.

Please see the example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx.  In this example, the array is already populated in the main class and then injected into an IEnumerable class.  Therefore this appears to eliminate the advantage of deferring the execution until later on.  What am I missing here?

Comment: The advantage is as for *every* interface to provide the least information to the caller possible. So instead of saying for a member "I need an array to work properly" you can also say: "I need some kind of collection which I can enumerate". So it doesn´t matter if it actually is an array, a list or even en (endless) stream.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is primarily about being able to iterate through zero or more instances of `T` - there is nothing implicit about enumerables that allows deferred execution. It happens, though, that LINQ provides a set of operators that do allowed deferred execution over enumerables. Those are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you reference is merely a *how could you implement it*, rather than *the most efficient way*. Of course, the implementation shown has no use at all, since as you say the array is already constructed and enumerable on itself.

The sample is useful at best to show how a custom type can act like a collection, by implementing `IEnumerable`. This very generic interface can of course be used to be called from a variety of places where you don't need specific knowledge about the collection type, but that isn't shown in the sample.

An enumerator is used to iterate over a set of data from begin to end. You can't read the previous item back since it can already be discarded (for example an iterator that needs to download very large files from a remote location, you might not want to cache them).

Comment: Is there a better example you can recommend, which shows how it could be used more efficiently? Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this documentation on `yield return`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) does, but no other source I can think of now.

Comment: A reminder of the Yield keyword (something I have not used for a while) was helpful here.  If something is going to act like a collection, then it surely should be a collection?

Comment: Not always. It can be a stream like collection, where items are obtained and discarded immediately.

Comment: "obtained and discarded immediately".  I like that.  Please add that to your answer.  I will then mark your answer.  Let me know once you have added it.

Comment: A collection is like a datatable.  A enumerable is like a data reader.  Is that right.

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The main purpose of an `IEnumerable` is *not* to defer execution until later. The purpose of an `IEnumerable` is to provide a way to iterate over the parts of an object. These parts can be the items of a list, but they can also be (for example) the characters of a `string`. The `IEnumerable` interface exists because not every class that allows iteration over its parts is a collection or a list (such as a `string`) and `IEnumerable` provides a minimal interface to achieve this without having to implement a full blown `ICollection` or `IList`.

The main and most important consumer of an `IEnumerable` is the `foreach` statement, which is there since the beginning of <strike>time</strike>.NET. Only later came LINQ with the `Enumerable` class that also builds on the `IEnumerable` (or more precisely on the `IEnumerable<T>`) interface.

Speaking of LINQ, the deferred execution you refer to in your question indeed is a key feature of LINQ. It means that a query that you define is not executed until the iteration of the `IEnumerable` is performed. This allows you to further refine your queries before you execute them.

This deferred execution though only refers to *how the* `IEnumerable` *is used*, not to *what it does*. Deferred execution means that you will not start to iterate over the `IEnumerable` when you define it, but at a different point in the program, for example a `foreach`, a `ToList` etc.

Comment: I'm not sure `string` is a very good counter-example. A `string` is nothing more than an array of `char`s. Otherwise you are spot on for the rest of it.

Comment: @gmiley - That's what Sefe is saying. He's pointing out that a `string` is an enumerable of `char`. He's correct.

Comment: @gmiley: A string is in fact not the same as an array of chars (even if internal storage is in a `char[]`). The key difference is that `char[]` is an `IList`, while `string` isn't. That's why I chose this example, because `string` is _only_ an `IEnumerable`, not even an `ICollection`.

Comment: I would have given an example of creating a class that implements `IEnumerable` that creates an IEnumerator that enumerates the properties of the class. If you like, I could edit your answer to add that example to the bottom and you can modify it how you like to incorporate it. I wont change anything else on your answer, just feel it would be a good addition.

Comment: @gmiley: To fully implement the IEnumerable interface you need to throw an InvalidOperationException if the object changes during enumeration (usually done with an enumerator version), so this is not as trivial as it seems (and probably too much for the OP). Maybe a link for further reading?

Answer (score 1):

One example of IEnumerable is late execution.

I thing that the bigs advantage of using an IEnumerable are:

1. You can iterate a collection without knowing how to iterate it (does the collection have an indexer? How should I iterate a Tree? etc.).
2. You can iterate a part of a collection - Think about finding the first element that meets your condition.
3. Late execution - You can filter collections and the real filtering will occur as soon as you traverse your IEnumerable (using ForEach\ToList etc.).

Comment: @HimBromBeere Nope. But before you had the IEnumerable interface, you needed to know how to iterate collections and other classes that are enumerables.

Answer (score 0):

It is a design choice whether to defer the evaluation or not, but is not mandated by IEnumerable. Some Linq output queries(like Where & Select) defer the evaluation, other collections like Dictionary or List don't.

You should use an IEnumerable when the only information you need from the collection is to be able to 'enumerate' the elements.

Let's say you want to implement a ToString method for a generic collection, where the object has its own ToString. If you accept an IEnumerable instead of an array, a List or a Set can be passed as argument, without any code changes.